# How to make top navigation vertically center with the logo?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the top menu vertically center without assigning value like `margin-top: 50px;` because some of my friends say this is not the ideal approach.

```css
/* Nav Section   */
 .nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-contain {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #2980B9;
    padding: 65px 50px 35px 45px;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#medical {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
}
.menu ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 45px;
}
.menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999px;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
    margin-left: 0;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-contain">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><span id="medical">Medical</span><span id="company"> Company</span></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Contain -->
</div>
<!-- Nav -->
```

Comment: Vertically center or Horizontally center? And did you mean the menu of "Home, About, Sample, Sample, Gallery, Prices, Contac"?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `float:right` on `.menu`, and set both `.logo` and `.menu` to this:

```
.logo, .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you need `.menu` to stay on far right side, also add this:

```
.nav-contain {
    text-align: justify; 
}
.nav-contain:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How it works:

1. Set `text-align: justify;` will line up the two inner inline blocks to the left and right edges of the container.
2. Create an invisible 100% width element by using `:after` or `:before` pseudo-element stretching the box to occupy the entire space of the container. Otherwise inline element occupies only the space bounded by the tags that define the inline element.

Comment: Your way looks simpler and has better support. Use this.

Comment: @Pangloss can you please tell me how to use this - 
content: ' '  or how it works

Comment: well, the sub menu is not working .. :/ please check

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to center here is to use Flexbox:

```
.nav-contain {
    /* what is already there */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Beware of browser support (check caniuse.com to see if the compatibility level is acceptable to you).

This is superior to the margin-top solution as it ensures that you won't have to manually change that 50px each time the size of the image or anything else in the navbar changes.

Comment: but it is driving the menu toward the logo ..i want to stick it to the right side

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.menu > ul > li {
    min-height:50px;
    display: table;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rawat/4h05rq2s/

Answer (score 0):

Since your navbar remains the same height the whole time, I suggest you give the `.nav-contain` the following code:

```
.nav-contain {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 184px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note the line-height.
This will, once you smaller the available width of your device, result in a probably not so nice looking huge navigation bar. For this, I suggest media queries.